# pandas reading date column in a strange way

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

hope you are all doing great;
I am in the middle of a small project regarding the analysis of TMDB, the data set is csv file with release_date column following M/D/Y

[image: screenshot for the csv file]

when reading the csv file in a jupyter notebook I used
`tmdb_df = pd.read_csv('tmdb-movies.csv', parse_dates=['release_date'])`
but the dates are not set correctly some date go to 2070 as pandas do this read a date like 4/5/1970 as 4/5/70.
how can I fix something like that? or how should i read the file

[image: screenshot for the csv loaded without parse_dates]

[image: same issue when loading the csv with parse_date]

Comment: Please format this properly. it's hard to read

Comment: **[No Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/)** of code or data. Always provide a [mre] with code, **data, errors, current output, and expected output**, as **[formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)**. If relevant, plot images are okay. Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Provide data with [How to provide a reproducible copy of your DataFrame using `df.head(10).to_clipboard(sep=',')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246), then **[edit] your question**, and paste the clipboard into a code block.

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Date'] = df["Date"].dt.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
```